# pygame.time.Clock.tick() por que não usar 60?

Tags: python, pygame

Por que a maioria usa 40 ao invés de 60? 60 fps não é mais considerado o ideal? Existe alguma recomendação para se usar 40? E se eu apenas chamar o método `tick` sem parâmetros?

Comment: Na verdade, depende mais da capacidade ocular de gerar imagens distintas. Se não me engano o olho humano chega a fazer 24 quadros por segundo. Uma taxa de 48 quadros por segundo é o dobro da capacidade humana, fazendo as imagens serem muito suaves. Não creio que haja muito diferença com 60 por segundo, porém isso vai custar muito mais processamento ao jogo

Comment: Gostaria de transformar isso numa resposta para ser votada?

Comment: Eu não tenho tanta certeza sobre a frequência do olho humano, só gosto de por como resposta quando eu tenho propriedade para falar do assunto. Um mínimo. Ainda preciso estudar um tanto mais. Talvez mais tarde essa semana eu consiga, talvez eu acabe esquecendo e alguém com conhecimento de causa dê uma resposta melhor do que seria a minha.